# Exception while fetching from local IP address with react-native in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, ip, fetch

I'm trying to fetch data from a local server in react-native using this code snippet:

```
fetch('http://192.168.1.10:8090', {...});
```

It works well in Android, also when I replace the local IP with a real domain name, it works in both Android and IOS. But for any local IP address (which is obviously accessible from the IOS device) it throws a meaningless exception and fails:

```
{"line": 107870, "column": 150, "sourceURL": "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false"}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are fetching an http address, and not https. You can add this domain as an exception domain in the info.plist.

Comment: But I can fetch other http domains (using their domain names)